# $.extend method with jquery bbq

Tags: jquery, object, extend

I define my routes object (jq bbq) and in some cases i have to add some new/additional to the already existing routes object with

```
$.extend(this.route, routeArray);
```

Is there a simple way to remove one route (or multiple routes) in the routearray? The order of the params varies.. Or is there a better way for doing this..?

How could i compare my routeArray with an copy of the previous routearray (lastRoute) and check if only a param changed wich doesn`t require a new ajaxget?

Exists there a easy possibility or have i to iterate over the routes object and check every param 
in the route object?

need me some advice . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Removing - delete routeArray['property']. If routeArray is real array and inherence from Array object, so you can you methods like splice, slice, pop, shift, etc. For more advanced information about delete you can check - http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/
2. You should compare each element in object with another object. Like this:

   for (var i in routeArray) {
       if (routeArray.hasOwnProperty(i) && routeArrayOriginal[i]) {
           //...
       }
   }

Comment: Ok i thought there is such a simple method like i could append an object with extend. But for me only your second suggestion will work i believe.